# C++ Memory management References

Tags: c++, memory-management

I am really confused about memory management in C++. What is the best reference (book or web) that deals with memory allocation, stack, heap, free store and scope & lifetime of variables.

Is there any resource that contrasts C++ memory allocation basics with that in C#?

Comment: .net and C++ have totally different ways of allocating memory. .NET is managed (i.e. garbage collected), in C++ your on your own!

Comment: @Esthapan you should really rephrase your question and tags then.

Comment: @Estephan: are you sure? Your question makes even less sense then: you cannot contrast C#’s and .NET’s memory management because they’re *the same*.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What is so confusing?

Answer (score 2):

[The C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/freestore-mgmt.html) deals with memory management issues extensively.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend [Expert C Programming: Deep C Secrets](http://www.powells.com/cgi-bin/biblio?inkey=4-0131774298-0) for learning all about these little details. It's got nothing to do with C++, but you'll learn almost everything you asked about :) and the writing is *superb*, which is pretty rare with C++ books.

Comment: Except that memory management in C++ is *very* different from C and you should *not* mix the two in C++ programs.

Comment: Agreed, but C is IMHO a much friendlier environment to learn about the stack, the heap, and variable scoping. Once you've got that down solid, it is easy to hear "new allocates an object off the stack" and know what it means.

Answer (score 0):

[RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) in conjunction with smart pointers ([std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)) is basically all you will need. If you stick with it you will get [exception safe](http://www.boost.org/community/exception_safety.html), memory leak free code :)